# Silverstripe PaginatedList - How to display record numbers on current page?

Tags: pagination, silverstripe

In silverstripe PaginatedList we can display Page numbers like **'Showing 1 of 5 Pages'**.
How to display record number on each page for example
**"Showing 1-10 record of 100"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a `PaginatedList`. Using [getTotalItems()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-PaginatedList.html#_getTotalItems) you can get the total number of items.

In your Template it's `$TotalItems` when you're inside the list's scope.

**edit:**
[$PageStart](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-PaginatedList.html#_getPageStart) gives you the start of the current page, [$PageLength](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-PaginatedList.html#_getPageLength) the amount of items on the current page, so you can calculate the end-number of the current items.

you can do this with an [Extension](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Extension.html) for `PaginatedList`, e.g.

```
class PaginatedListEndNumberExtension extends Extension {

    public function getPageEnd() {
        return $this->owner->getPageStart() + $this->owner->getPageLength()
    }
}
```

and in your */mysite/_config/config.yml*

```
PaginatedList:
  extensions:
    - PaginatedListEndNumberExtension
```

So in your template with `$PageEnd` you get the end number of the current page.

Code untested but should get you started. You'll have to check if the end number is greater the number of total items, but i'll leave this exercise up to you ;)

Comment: yes I know that. but how to get first and last record numbers i.e "showing 1-10" or "showing 30-35" ?

Comment: Hi Sneha, i updated my anser. Feel free to accept it if it helps you solving your problem.

Comment: Hey thanks for solving my problem. It worked. However `$TotalItems` didn't work. It shows _method does not exist in datalist_ beacause I'm using it outside loop I guess. So I used `$PaginatedList.Count`. Thanks Again.

Comment: I have another issue. Can you please help to solve it?

Comment: Please ask a new question for other issues... or join us on IRC; freenode #silvestripe .. or both ;)

Comment: yes I have asked a new question. here is the link  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908710/silverstripe-swipestripe-swipestripe-gallery-module-error/)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this recently - This is default functionality since at least Silverstripe 3. No need for any extensions.
API Docs: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/templates/how_tos/pagination/

Two variables you need:

```
$FirstItem
$LastItem
```

e.g.

```
Showing $Results.FirstItem - $Results.LastItem of $Results.TotalItems
```