# SilverStripe Swipestripe - swipestripe-gallery module error

Tags: silverstripe, swipestripe

I've installed Swipestripe module. and added **swipestripe-gallery** module for product images.
when I did *dev/bulid?flush=1* it shows error **Class 'Gallery_PageExtension' does not exists**
I have seen gallery.yml file in swipestripe-gallery/_config folder, which has

```
Product:
   extensions: 
     - 'Gallery_PageExtension'
```

but this class is not there in Product.php file in swipestripe-gallery/code folder.
After commenting above code I did *dev/build?flush=1* & there was no error. But in product page the Gallery tab is not added.
Please Help.

Comment: Well, Product class can be in another module, that doesn't matter. Have you installed it using composer? Does a Product.php exist anywhere in /swipestripe/code/ ? Also - flush again ;) Are the tables generated in Database? Did /dev/build/ quit without error? please doublecheck.

Comment: @wmk Yes I've checked it. And the thing is if a class is there it will be added as extension. But There is no class named "Gallery_PageExtension" in this module. then how it supposed to be added as extension ? and dev/build doesn't quit without error if above code is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't install using composer? Your fault ;) It installs all requirements for you and you can code happy.

See https://github.com/swipestripe/silverstripe-swipestripe-gallery#requirements, you'll need to install https://github.com/frankmullenger/silverstripe-gallery for getting this gallery extension in your codebase.

I strongly encourage you to install ALL modules with composer. It may be a bit hard in the beginning, but in some days your life will be much more comfortable! [A good introduction can be found in the ss docs.](http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/getting_started/composer/)

Comment: Ohh! I actually didn't paid attention to this as I'm running out of time to complete my site. Thanks a lot. You saved my time. & yes I didn't used composer. but will surely use from next time so that I don't get stuck in such situation. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

Swipestripe's config does not have that code: https://github.com/swipestripe/silverstripe-swipestripe/blob/2.1/_config/swipestripe.yaml

The gallery module for it does: https://github.com/swipestripe/silverstripe-swipestripe-gallery/blob/1.1/_config/gallery.yml

These are two separate modules. If the gallery file is in swipestripe/_config as you say, then it would seem to me that the install didn't happen as it should.

There should be two folders in your installation root

- swipestripe/
- swipestripe-gallery/

All files relating to each module should be in each (individual) folder. It seems you're missing the swipestripe-gallery folder all together, meaning that the class in fact does not exist (When you get this error, just check that the class exists somewhere in your install. Using grep is the easiest way).

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question. yes there are two modules. and the code is in swipestripe-gallery/_config/gallery.yml. By mistake I typed swipestripe instead of swipestripe-gallery